# how to add "Portal" namespace? What code should I add?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to create pages in my private wiki with the prefix "portal" without success, I understand that I have to add code in order for this to happen, what do I have to add?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in `LocalSettings.php`:

```php
define ('NS_PORTAL'     , 198);
define ('NS_PORTAL_TALK', 199);
$wgExtraNamespaces  [NS_PORTAL]     = 'Portal';
$wgExtraNamespaces  [NS_PORTAL_TALK]= 'Portal_talk';
```

Further reading: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Using_custom_namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I actually added the following code:

```
define( 'Portal', 126 );
define( 'Portal_Talk', 127 );

$wgExtraNamespaces += [
126 => 'Portal',
127 => 'Portal_Talk',
];

$wgNonincludableNamespaces += [ 126, 127 ];

$wgNamespaceRobotPolicies += [
'Portal' => 'index, follow',
'Portal_Talk' => 'noindex, nofollow',
];

$wgNamespacesWithSubpages += [
'Portal' => true,
];
$wgContentNamespaces = [ 0, 126 ];
```